# MS Teams grab Assignment Data

Tags: python, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to write smth in python which lists all my Assigments over all Teams. Is there a way to grab this data? I think the "pymsteams" library is just for writing messages. Am I right?

Comment: what is an "assignment"? Something to do with education in Teams, or do you mean a task assigned to you in Planner  or ToDo (which appear as "Tasks" in Teams)?

Comment: I'm student and a teacher can create Assignments = exercises. There's a tab in each Team called "Assignments". But there's no option to list all assignments over all teams. I'm trying to do this.

Comment: There is no API available to fetch the data of channel tabs in multiple teams

Comment: Unfortunately even Microsoft's own tool "Power Automate" cannot do this.
They really have to implement that.